# Add a line break after the title of an horizontal legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

When `theme(legend.position = "top")`, the legend is horizontal and can be a bit too wide.

Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(5,6) + 
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: plot]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In order to reduce the width of the legend, I'd like to add a line break after the "Species" title.

I'm aware of `guides(guide_legend(ncol=2,nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))`, it is very nice but it yeilds a different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `title.position` argument in [`guide_legend`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html) in `scale_colour_discrete`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(5,6) + 
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

[image]

Comment: great! Couldn't find this option.